# sftp connection failed, strange error messsage

Tags: networking, command-line, sftp

While I am trying to connect to a remote system from terminal using sftp

`sftp user@host.ip.address`

connection is failing and a message coming

> Received message too long < some long number >

I connect that machine frequently, can not understand what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have to do with a message (like welcoming message) popping up after the successful login. `sftp` fails to connect in this situation (see http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#2.9).

Try to `ssh` in the same server and see if any message pops up. It should be started from one of these file `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile,`~/.bashrc, or other shell initialization file. You can then comment out the respective line from there.

Comment: problem is solved, last time I put `echo "some text"` in my `~/.bashrc`. thanks.