# Does Ubuntu handle 'bash_profile' differently from OS X in subshells?

Tags: bash, bashrc, .profile

On my OS X system, when I use a subshell (for example with `screen`), the settings in my `.bash_profile` are inherited, but on Ubuntu, they are not, and in order to get the same behavior I have on OS X I have to add

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

to the start of my `.bashrc`.

Does Ubuntu (Linux) handle the relationship between `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` and their use in subshells differently from OS X (BSD)? Is there an Ubuntu setting that makes it behave like OS X in this regard so that I can avoid the above line?

Comment: @DavidFoerster: So OS X (BSD) and Ubuntu (Linux) behave exactly the same, and I should look to the contents of my `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` to see what differs there between the two systems I have?

Comment: @DavidFoerster: It looks like [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/432508/231332) may also be (even more) relevant; and be the start of an answer here.

Comment: I tend to believe that the profile and shell start-up script behaviour is standardized for all *nices (e. g. BSD and Linux, OS X and Ubuntu). Ultimately that would be a question worth asking on [Unix.SE] though.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Maybe. But I can't reconcile that with what I'm seeing. On OS X, the settings from my `~/.bash_profile` are in effect when I `screen`, and those in `~/.bashrc` are as well (I get the effect of the former followed by the latter). But on Ubuntu, I get only the latter (`~/.bash_profile` settings are not used). Perhaps there's a `screen` setting on Ubuntu that does not inherit the parent shell's settings?

Comment: @DavidFoerster: I think I've found half of the answer [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/119711/439): on OS X `.bashrc` is *not* sourced by `.bash_profile`. That leaves the questions of how `screen` inherits (a) inherits all of `.bash_profile` (when Ubuntu does not) and (b) also reads `.bashrc`.