# My bash aliases stopped working after a recent update.

Tags: bashrc

But, they still work after `source .bash_aliases`.

I have the following lines in my .bashrc:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

This is supposed to be equivalent to typing `source .bash_aliases`, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, looks like it should work. Do you have to `source` the file explicitly every time you start a shell?

Comment: Yeah, exactly.

I do have my .bash_aliases stored in my Dropbox, with ~/.bash_aliases as a symlink to ~/Dropbox/.bash_aliases, but that shouldn't matter, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out; it was caused by my having created a .bash_profile in following a tutorial to set up a GPG key. In the presence of a .bash_profile file, the entire .bashrc file is ignored.

Comment: It's not that the `.bash_profile` file causes the `.bashrc` to be ignored. The situations in which bash sources the two are different. However, `.bash_profile` takes precedence over `.profile`, which is used by default on Ubuntu, and the default Ubuntu version sources `.bashrc`: http://askubuntu.com/questions/432508/why-does-ubuntus-default-profile-source-bashrc, hence the overall effect.

Answer (score 0):

From `man [`:

```
   -f FILE
          FILE exists and is a regular file
```

Since you made .bash_aliases a link, this test is failing. Either make it a regular file and not a soft link, or change this test.

Comment: Hmm... `man bash` says *"Unless otherwise specified, primaries that operate on files follow symbolic links and operate on the target of the link, rather than the link itself."* though

Comment: @steeldriver hmm, I just tried it myself and you're right. Maybe Dropbox is doing something funny to the link target.

Comment: I did try fixing it this way and unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the same alias in `bash_profile` file also. And restart your terminal