# Which script loads bash startup scripts?

Tags: bash, startup

I'm interested to know which script file(s) on Ubuntu loads startup files like .bashrc or .bash_profile? Any hint or reference is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part [Bash loads them itself](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html). The exceptions are:

- [`/etc/profile`](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files/tree/share/profile), which loads `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`
- [`~/.profile`, which loads `~/.bashrc`](https://askubuntu.com/q/432508/301745)

This applies to Debian as well btw.